# PHP how to use $_GET with char '&' in it?

Tags: php, mysqli

Am trying to use $_GET with char '&' in it since the data in database are categorized using '&' between 2 words, but as storing $_GET in a variable it shows the first word like if:

Stack & Flow => $_GET=Stack

how to fix this without changing the whole database.

Or is there anyway to use 'Start With' in msqli query?

Answer (score 1):

Basics of HTTP request methods.

In `GET` method you use `URL` as medium and you pass data with syntax:

`?variable=value&another_variable=value123`

Where `&` is separator. You need to encode it.

`urlencode('&')`

Comment: oh okey, it would take more time to do that since am posting category names right from database, so i have to split before building URL right?

Comment: the category nav is been build dynamically like this:        $query="Select * from categories";
    $results = $mysqli -> query($query);
    if($results){
     $cat;
     while($row = $results -> fetch_assoc())
      {$cat=$row["cat_NAME"];
      echo '<a href="products.php?type='.$cat.'">'.$cat.'</a>';}}